# how to enable Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY in the android versions more than 4?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am using Android version 4.4
But below condition is not true in the function onsensorchanged():

```
if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY)
 gravityValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
else
 System.out.println("Gravity sensor not supported");
```

My devices running (4.1 and 4.4) are printing msg in the else part.
could any body tell me how to enable that sensor.

Comment: Your code will not even compile, as `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` is not a `boolean`.

Comment: i this is returning false:
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);

Comment: `getDefaultSensor()` returns a `Sensor`, not a `boolean`.